# Issue using Reader.onloadend: read previous data

Tags: angular, recordrtc

I'm trying to understand a code developed by another person. Briefly, I need to record an audio stream from the microphone and send it to Google API Speech Recongition system.

We are using recordrtc.

I have a button that, if pressed, records the audio and then, pressed again, stops the recording.

The problem is in the stop recording function. Using the reader.onloadend, when I try to read the audio, always I read the previous audio and not the new one, like I'm in a loop and I read the i-1 data insted the i-th.

here the code of the stopRecording:

```
stopRecording() {
    if (this.isRecording) {
      this.audioRecordingService.stopRecording();
      this.isRecording = false;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.ccc.blob); 
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        console.log("onloadend")
            var base64data = reader.result;
            localStorage.setItem("audioData", base64data.toString());                   
    }
    var data = localStorage.getItem("audioData");
    var clean_data =  data.substr(data.indexOf(',')+1);
    var post_obj = JSON.stringify({
        "name":"audio",
        "base64": clean_data
    })
    this.commandList.postBlob(post_obj).subscribe((res) => {
       console.log("Google API translation: "+ res["res"]);
    });
 }
```

Sorry if something is missing.

thanks

---

To ble totally clear, I also added the functions in the audio-recording-service. Hope this help. I also checked and I can confirm that he used recordRTC

```
 getRecordedBlob(): Observable<RecordedAudioOutput> {
   return this._recorded.asObservable();
 }

 getRecordedTime(): Observable<string> {
   return this._recordingTime.asObservable();
 }

 recordingFailed(): Observable<string> {
   return this._recordingFailed.asObservable();
 }

 startRecording() {
   if (this.recorder) {
     return;
   }

   this._recordingTime.next('00:00');
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(s => {
   this.stream = s;
   this.record();
 }).catch(error => {
  this._recordingFailed.next();
 });
}

abortRecording() {
  this.stopMedia();
}

private record() {
  this.recorder = new RecordRTC.StereoAudioRecorder(this.stream, {
  type: 'audio',
  numberOfAudioChannels: 1, // or leftChannel:true
  mimeType: 'audio/webm'
});

this.recorder.record();
this.startTime = moment();
this.interval = setInterval(
  () => {
    const currentTime = moment();
    const diffTime = moment.duration(currentTime.diff(this.startTime));
    const time = this.toString(diffTime.minutes()) + ':' + this.toString(diffTime.seconds());
    this._recordingTime.next(time);
  },
  1000
 );
}

 private toString(value) {
   let val = value;
   if (!value) {
   val = '00';
 }
 if (value < 10) {
   val = '0' + value;
 }
 return val;
}

stopRecording() {
  if (this.recorder) {
    this.recorder.stop((blob) => {
      if (this.startTime) {
        const mp3Name = encodeURIComponent('audio_' + new Date().getTime() + '.mp3');
        this.stopMedia();
        this._recorded.next({ blob: blob, title: mp3Name });
      }
     }, () => {
       this.stopMedia();
       this._recordingFailed.next();
     });
  }
} 

 private stopMedia() {
   if (this.recorder) {
     this.recorder = null;
     clearInterval(this.interval);
     this.startTime = null;
     if (this.stream) {
       this.stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
       this.stream = null;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Did you try this? `var blob = recorder.getBlob(); reader.readAsDataURL(blob);` i.e. use "getBlob" to access blob object.

Comment: Hi @MuazKhan thanks for the answer. One question: what is "recorder"? I don't have this variable in this part of the code

Comment: `recorder=RecordRTC(stream,options)` and stopRecording MUST look like this: `recorder.stopRecording(function() {})` and your codes must reside inside stopRecording callback. I can see that you are accessing blob outside stopRecording callback. Please move code inside of "recorder.stopRecording". Ref: https://recordrtc.org/RecordRTC.html#blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
stopRecording() {
    if (this.isRecording) {
        var that = this;
        this.audioRecordingService.stopRecording(function() {
            that.ccc.blob = that.audioRecordingService.getBlob();
            stopRecording(); // this line is tricky; maybe "that.stopRecording()"?
        });
        this.isRecording = false;
        return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.ccc.blob);
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        console.log("onloadend")
        var base64data = reader.result;
        localStorage.setItem("audioData", base64data.toString());
    }
    var data = localStorage.getItem("audioData");
    var clean_data = data.substr(data.indexOf(',') + 1);
    var post_obj = JSON.stringify({
        "name": "audio",
        "base64": clean_data
    })
    this.commandList.postBlob(post_obj).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log("Google API translation: " + res["res"]);
    });
}
```

i.e. I changed this in your code:

```
audioRecordingService.stopRecording(function() {
    var blob = audioRecordingServices.getBlob();
});
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your time. Unfortunately, the code was written by another guy and probably he modified the audioRecordingService. In fact, I got an error "Expected 0 arguments got 1" in audioRecordingService.stopRecording

Comment: Please verify if he is using RecordRTC. If he is using RecordRTC then he must be using something like "recorder.stopRecording" internally somewhere. You can tell him that put codes inside stopRecording callback. Also ask him to use "getBlob". Hope this helps. Regards

Comment: I added another part of the code regarding the audio service. Hope this will help

Comment: Do you want to get intervals based audio blobs then read them using FileReader? E.g. get every one second's audio-blob and convert into DataURI and upload to google translation service? If yes, then [here is the demo](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/simple-demos/ondataavailable.html). It supports StereoAudioRecorder as well however I'll recommend main "RecordRTC" object which will chose MediaRecorder API if available otherwise fallbacks to WebAudio solution.

Comment: @MuazKhan Could you please look into 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731348/how-to-send-and-receive-desktop-capture-stream-generated-via-getusermedia